# Error bound for non-composite Newton-Cotes formula

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I am working on a question and I am stuck, wish to find some help.

The question ask me to find the error bound for approximating the following integral by consider $n=4$ non-composite Newton-Cotes formula:
$$\int^{1.2}_0 x^3 \tanh(0.5x) dx$$
The error term of $n=4$ non-composite Newton-Cotes formula is $\frac{8h^7}{945}f^{(6)}(\zeta)$.

So I calculate out the 6th derivative for the integral, and get $$E=\frac{8\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)}{945}M = 0.0000277709$$ which $M=\max\limits_{x\in[a,b]}|f^{(6)}(\zeta)|$.

Then I am stuck, what can I do next?

Comment: Like the Trapezium and Simpson’s rules, Newton-Cotes formulas which are obtained by integrating of an interpolating polynomial for interpolation points x0,...,xn. I have double check the question, I think maybe here is ask me to use boole’s rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error bound is given by:
\begin{equation*}
E=\frac{8\left(\frac{1.2-0}{4}\right)^7}{945}M
\end{equation*}
Where $M=30$, $E=0.00005554285714$.

[$f^{(6)}(x)$ over $x \in[0,1.2]$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCdJ1.png)

Comment: Why M=30? I get a different value for M by differentiate.

Comment: $f^{(6)}(0) = -30$, so $\mid f^{(6)}(\zeta)\mid = 30$. You have forgotten to take the absolute value. so you have chosen $f^{(6)}(1.2) = 14.99...$ which is explains the difference in error bound.

Comment: Oh, I got it, thank you so much!